# "recompile with Xdiags:verbose to get full output"

Tags: java

al compilar con javac me da en error.  "recompile with Xdiags:verbose to get full output"
el problema sencillamente debe evaluar y compara elementos ingresados por teclado que le son requeridos al usuario.
Me pueden ayudar a detectarlo?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Vacaciones{
   public static void main(String args[]){

    String nombre="";
    int anios=0, dpto=0;
    Scanner intro = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
    nombre = intro.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Cuantos años de servicio tiene: ");
    anios= intro.nextInt();

    System.out.println("cual es su departamento'1 - 2 - 3':");
    dpto = intro.nextInt();

    if(dpto==1){
      System.out.println("1");

    }else if (dpto==2) {
      System.out.println("2");

    }else if (dpto==3) {
      System.out.println("3");
    }else {
      System.out.println("error");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: El mensaje es claro. debes agregar el parámetro `-Xdiags:verbose` a tu comando de compilación para que te muestre los problemas que encontró: `javac -Xdiags:verbose ...`. La traza que te muestre el comando la puedes compartir aquí para ayudarte.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!! ya pude compilar!!!!!

Comment: Agrega una respuesta @E.Betanzos :-)

Comment: @E.Betanzos seguimos adelante!! gracias

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia @Jorgesys, está hecho ;-)

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje es claro: debes agregar el parámetro `-Xdiags:verbose` a tu comando de compilación para que el compilador te muestre los problemas que encontró:

```
$ javac -Xdiags:verbose ...
```

Si los problemas que te muestra la traza de diagnóstico (que es lo que genera ese parámetro) no sabes como resolverlos, compártela aquí para ayudarte con eso.